# Gradio pop up display on success

Tags: python, fastapi, gradio

Here is the below sample code for gradio app mounted on FAST API app.

```py
import gradio as gr
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.responses import RedirectResponse
from starlette.requests import Request

app = FastAPI()


def submit(message):
    print(f"Saving message: {message}")


@app.get('/')
async def homepage(request: Request):
    return RedirectResponse(url='/home')


with gr.Blocks(title="TEST") as demo:
    gr.Markdown("TEST APP NAME")
    with gr.Row():
        with gr.Column():
            message = gr.components.Textbox(label="Message", interactive=True)
    btn3 = gr.Button("Save")
    btn3.click(
        submit,
        inputs=[message],
        outputs=None
    ).success(None, _js="window.location.reload()")

gradio_app = gr.mount_gradio_app(app, demo, "/home")
```

Output of above sample code:
[image]

How to have a Success pop up message e.g. "Submit Successful" on pressing the Save button.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something like what you've mentioned
I just used

```
raise gr.Error("something here")
```

To inform the user by something